# Magento product update using api and sybase

Tags: php, api, magento, soap, sybase

Im trying to update my product price using magento api but it fails for bulk data

```
$result = sybase_query("SELECT PartCode,CurrBasicSalesPrice FROM BasicCustPartSalesPrice WHERE CustId='FOO'"); //around 654 results   

while ($row = sybase_fetch_object($result) ) { 
try {
 $r = $this->_client->call($this->_session, 'product.update', array($row->PartCode, array('price' => $row->CurrBasicSalesPrice)));

}catch(Exception $e){

  echo $e->getMessage();  
}
}
```

If i use this query this will work fine

```
  sybase_query("SELECT PartCode,CurrBasicSalesPrice FROM BasicCustPartSalesPrice WHERE CustId='FOO' AND someother='bar'"); //around 30 results
```

If there any limitations for bulk update using api ?

Comment: Have you tried using `$this->_client->multiCall($this->_session, array(array('product.update', array(params1)), array('product.update', array(params2)), ...)` ? More info: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bulk updating anything on standard Magento generally causes issues.  You may want to look at 3rd party alternatives for product updates like Urapidflow or Magmi.